# PHP - wkhtmltopdf binary file

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, x86-64, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using the [wkhtml2pdf libary](https://github.com/NitMedia/wkhtml2pdf) in my Laravel application. On my local environment this works perfectly. My PDF is correctly generated. In my **.env** file I have:

> WKHTML2PDF_BIN_FILE=wkhtmltopdf-amd64

But on my [scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com/) server I have the following error:

[image]

My software supports **armhf**. So I couldn't install the amd/64-bit versions. I've installed wkhtmltopdf on my server like this:

```
sudo apt install wkhtmltopd
```

But now it's not working online. I think my config is wrong (the link to the bin file). But how can I know and set the correct link to my WKHTML2PDF_BIN_FILE?

**UPDATE:**

When I enter the following commmand:

```
sudo find / -name "wkhtmltopdf*"
```

Then I get the following results:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/wkhtmltopdf.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/wkhtmltopdf.list
/var/www/mydomain.com/html/vendor/nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf/src/Nitmedia/Wkhtml2pdf/lib/wkhtmltopdf-i386
/var/www/mydomain.com/html/vendor/nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf/src/Nitmedia/Wkhtml2pdf/lib/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
/var/www/mydomain.com/html/vendor/nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf/src/Nitmedia/Wkhtml2pdf/lib/wkhtmltopdf-0.12.1-OS-X.i386
/usr/share/doc/wkhtmltopdf
/usr/share/man/man1/wkhtmltopdf.1.gz
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

I've tried to change the `WKHTML2PDF_BIN_FILE=wkhtmltopdf-amd64` to `WKHTML2PDF_BIN_FILE=/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf` but that results in:

[image]

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE 2:**

I've added this to my config:

```
WKHTML2PDF_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/ 
WKHTML2PDF_BIN_FILE=wkhtmltopdf
```

But then I'm getting the error **QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display**. I've read in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192642/wkhtmltopdf-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-display) topic that I should be able to run it with *xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf*. But where should I add this in the library?

Comment: `sudo find / -name "wkhtmltopdf*"` will give you the exact path.

Comment: @aynber, I've updated topic with results. Could you help me on my way?

Comment: [This might help](https://github.com/NitMedia/wkhtml2pdf/issues/49).

Comment: In the exception, there is a double // in the path
Try setting WKHTML2PDF_BIN_FILE=usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf without the leading / . Also, try 'which wkhtmltopdf' to find out where linux sees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the code of the library [in this block of code](https://github.com/NitMedia/wkhtml2pdf/blob/master/src/Nitmedia/Wkhtml2pdf/Wkhtml2pdf.php#L144-L160) it looks for the binary filename and the binary file path, which are two seperate things.

So maybe you have to add two env params instead of one:

```
WKHTML2PDF_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/
WKHTML2PDF_BIN_FILE=wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: can you please post your config file where the wkhtml2pdf is configured not the `.env` file

Comment: because if you add the config to the `.env` without adding the config in the real configuration file that reads from the `.env` it will be as if you did not do anything

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this issue thread here https://github.com/NitMedia/wkhtml2pdf/issues/33

Create a config file:

```
app/config/packages/nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf/local/config.php
```

And add the paths inside it:

```
return [
    'debug' => true,
    'binpath' => '/usr/bin/',
    'binfile' => 'wkhtmltopdf',
    'tmppath' => '/tmp/',
];
```

And don't fortget to delete the `.env` config entry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this on your server's teminal;

`export DISPLAY=:0`

Effectively duping the display.